# d3: color a line based on another dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to color a rectangle by the value of a dataset.

Here is an example where I plot a sine-wave and color the line by the y-value (from red to blue as the y-value changes from 1 to -1).

What I would like is to have a bar that is colored by that y-value.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sanandak/m2jryr22/11/

(apologies for my prior post where the fiddle was missing!)

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
svg.attr('width', 300).attr('height', 300)

data = d3.range(0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.1)
  .map(function(t) {
    return {
      x: t,
      y: Math.sin(t)
    };
  });

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  .range([10, 290])

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([150, 10])

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  });

svg.append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "line-gradient")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", yScale(-1))
  .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", yScale(1))
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data([{
    "offset": "0%",
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    "offset": "100%",
    color: "red"
  }])
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d) {
    return d.offset;
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })

svg.append('g')
  .datum(data)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', line)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#line-gradient)')

svg.append('g')
  .datum(data)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 160)
  .attr('width', 280)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#line-gradient)')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after.  Your gradient covers a range of 140 pixels.  Your bar covers a range of 20.  You won't see any of the gradient in the bar.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show what I am trying to do.  I used a series of 'rect', each colored differently.  I think there should be an easier way...?  https://jsfiddle.net/sanandak/m2jryr22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now.  I would define a complex gradient matching your y values across the x domain:

```
var c = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1,1])
  .range(['blue', 'red'])

svg.append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "line-gradient2")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("x1", 10).attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", 280).attr("y2", 0)
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('stop')
  .attr('stop-color', function(d){
    return c(d.y);
  })
  .attr('offset',function(d){
    return (d.x/xScale.domain()[1] * 100) + '%';
  });
```

Here's it is in action:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
svg.attr('width', 300).attr('height', 300)

data = d3.range(0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.1)
  .map(function(t) {
    return {
      x: t,
      y: Math.sin(t)
    };
  });

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  .range([10, 290])

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([150, 10])
  
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  });

svg.append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "line-gradient")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", yScale(-1))
  .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", yScale(1))
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data([{
    "offset": "0%",
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    "offset": "100%",
    color: "red"
  }])
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d) {
    return d.offset;
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  
 var c = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([-1,1])
 .range(['blue', 'red'])
  
svg.append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "line-gradient2")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("x1", 10).attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", 280).attr("y2", 0)
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('stop')
  .attr('stop-color', function(d){
   return c(d.y);
  })
  .attr('offset',function(d){
   return (d.x/xScale.domain()[1] * 100) + '%';
  });

svg.append('g')
  .datum(data)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', line)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#line-gradient)')

svg.append('g')
  .datum(data)
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 160)
  .attr('width', 280)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#line-gradient2)')
 
var rWidth = 280 / (data.length -1);
svg.append('g')
     .selectAll('rect')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', function(d) {return xScale(d.x);})
     .attr('y', 200)
     .attr('width', rWidth)
     .attr('height', 20)
     .attr('stroke', 'none')
     .attr('fill', function(d) {return c(d.y);})
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```